# Memory usage goes high when exporting data to excel using EPPPlus library

Tags: c#, excel-2010, epplus

I am exporting data available in a DataSet to excel file using EPPlus library. Number for rows can be between 1000 to 300000 with 10-15 columns. We are running queries which can generated files ranging from small number of records to large sets. During export memory increases by few hundred MB for one export file.

Questions: Is this expected behavior? I know there are tools which are available to profile memory. I want to understand which is the best tool I can use?

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx
2. http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/
3. http://memprofiler.com/
4. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `CLR Profiler` alongside with `Eqatec Profiler`. They're really good in checking memory usages on your variables checking performance of your application. I also use them for determining bottlenecks. Most of all. They're FREE! :D

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, I am gonna use these tools. I just loved your display pic :-)